# python C extensions - argument check in constructor

Tags: python, c

I have this small python extension that works perfectly except for the fact that arguments of the constructor of class Levtree (which is the levtree_levtree_init function in the C code) are not checked, the function takes a tuple of strings as the only argument, if I call the constructor in a python script with a different argument type or number , segfault is the result, in spite of the usual TypeError, (that works instead for the other method Levtree.search). What's missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "levtree.h"
#include <python2.7/Python.h>
#include <python2.7/structmember.h>


typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    levtree *tree;
    PyObject *wordlist;
    /* Type-specific fields go here. */
} levtree_levtree_obj;

static int
levtree_clear(levtree_levtree_obj *self)
{
    PyObject *tmp;

    tmp = self->wordlist;
    self->wordlist = NULL;
    Py_XDECREF(tmp);
    return 0;
}

static void
levtree_dealloc(levtree_levtree_obj* self)
{
    levtree_clear(self);
    levtree_free(self->tree);
    free(self->tree);
    self->ob_type->tp_free((PyObject*)self);
}

static PyObject *
levtree_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    levtree_levtree_obj *self;

    self = (levtree_levtree_obj *)type->tp_alloc(type, 0);
    if (self != NULL) {
        self->tree = NULL;
    }
    return (PyObject *)self;
}

static int
levtree_levtree_init(levtree_levtree_obj *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    int numLines;       /* how many lines we passed for parsing */
    char** carg;        /* argument to pass to the C function*/
    unsigned i;

    PyObject * strObj;  /* one string in the list */

    /* the O! parses for a Python object (listObj) checked
       to be of type PyList_Type */
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple( args, "O!", &PyTuple_Type, &self->wordlist))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    Py_INCREF(self->wordlist);
    /* get the number of lines passed to us */
    numLines = PyTuple_Size(self->wordlist);
    carg = malloc(sizeof(char*)*numLines);

    /* should raise an error here. */
    if (numLines < 0)
    {
        return -1; /* Not a list */
    }


    /* iterate over items of the list, grabbing strings, and parsing
       for numbers */
    for (i=0; i<numLines; i++)
    {

        /* grab the string object from the next element of the list */
        strObj = PyTuple_GetItem(self->wordlist, i); /* Can't fail */

        /* make it a string */
        carg[i] = PyString_AsString( strObj );
    }
    self->tree = (levtree*) malloc(sizeof(levtree));
    levtree_init(self->tree,carg,numLines);
    free(carg);
    return 0;
}

static PyObject *
levtree_levtree_search(levtree_levtree_obj* self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    char* wordkey;
    index_t number_of_matches=1;
    byte_t case_sensitive=0;
    index_t i;
    PyObject* boolean;
    static char *kwlist[] = {"wordkey","number_of_matches","case_sensitive", NULL};
    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwds, "s|iO", kwlist,
                                      &wordkey, &number_of_matches,&boolean))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if(PyObject_IsTrue(boolean))
    {
        case_sensitive=1;
    }
    if(number_of_matches > self->tree->entry_count) // if some idiot enters a number of results bigger than the list of words given in the constructor
    {
        number_of_matches = self->tree->entry_count;
    }
    self->tree->case_sensitive=case_sensitive;
    //printf("matches: %u", number_of_matches);
    levtree_search(self->tree, wordkey, number_of_matches);
    levtree_result res;
    PyObject* tmp, *string;
    PyObject* list = PyList_New(number_of_matches);
    for(i=0; i<number_of_matches; i++)
    {
        res = levtree_get_result(self->tree,i);
        string = PyTuple_GetItem(self->wordlist,res.id);
        //printf("%p\t id: %u\n",string,res.id);
        tmp = Py_BuildValue("(OI)",string,res.distance);
        PyList_SetItem(list,i,tmp);
    }
    return list;
}

static PyMemberDef Levtree_members[] =
{
    //    {"standing", T_OBJECT_EX, offsetof(Levtree, ), 0,
    //     "Match standing"},
    {NULL}  /* Sentinel */
};


static PyMethodDef Levtree_methods[] =
{
    {"search", levtree_levtree_search, METH_KEYWORDS, "Levenshtein tree search method"},
    //{"result", levtree_get_result_py, METH_VARARGS, "Levenshtein tree get result method"},
    {NULL}  /* Sentinel */
};

static PyTypeObject levtree_levtree_type =
{
    PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
    0,                         /*ob_size*/
    "levtree.Levtree",             /*tp_name*/
    sizeof(levtree_levtree_obj), /*tp_basicsize*/
    0,                         /*tp_itemsize*/
    (destructor)levtree_dealloc,                         /*tp_dealloc*/
    0,                         /*tp_print*/
    0,                         /*tp_getattr*/
    0,                         /*tp_setattr*/
    0,                         /*tp_compare*/
    0,                         /*tp_repr*/
    0,                         /*tp_as_number*/
    0,                         /*tp_as_sequence*/
    0,                         /*tp_as_mapping*/
    0,                         /*tp_hash */
    0,                         /*tp_call*/
    0,                         /*tp_str*/
    0,                         /*tp_getattro*/
    0,                         /*tp_setattro*/
    0,                         /*tp_as_buffer*/
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT,        /*tp_flags*/
    "Levensthein distance tree",           /* tp_doc */
    0,                     /* tp_traverse */
    (inquiry)levtree_clear,                    /* tp_clear */
    0,                     /* tp_richcompare */
    0,                     /* tp_weaklistoffset */
    0,                     /* tp_iter */
    0,                     /* tp_iternext */
    Levtree_methods,             /* tp_methods */
    Levtree_members,             /* tp_members */
    0,                         /* tp_getset */
    0,                         /* tp_base */
    0,                         /* tp_dict */
    0,                         /* tp_descr_get */
    0,                         /* tp_descr_set */
    0,                         /* tp_dictoffset */
    (initproc)levtree_levtree_init,      /* tp_init */
    0,                         /* tp_alloc */
    levtree_new,                 /* tp_new */
};

#ifndef PyMODINIT_FUNC  /* declarations for DLL import/export */
#define PyMODINIT_FUNC void
#endif
PyMODINIT_FUNC
initlevtree(void)
{
    PyObject* m;
    levtree_levtree_type.tp_new = PyType_GenericNew;
    if (PyType_Ready(&levtree_levtree_type) < 0)
        return;

    m = Py_InitModule3("levtree", NULL,
                       "Example module that creates an extension type.");

    Py_INCREF(&levtree_levtree_type);
    PyModule_AddObject(m, "Levtree", (PyObject *)&levtree_levtree_type);
}
```

Comment: Can you show *how* are you calling the constructor? Also note you are not checking whether the *elements* of the tuple are strings, so it is perfectly normal that `PyString_AsString` fails when you pass non-strings inside the tuple argument...

Comment: No,no, that's not the problem, I didn't even try to pass non String Object into the tuple, even though as you pointed out this would surely fail, but my problem is that segfault is the result even if I pass for example a tuple of string AND an integer, or a List of strings, besides that I do not understand what you mean when you say

Comment: - show how are you calling the constructor, the only call is the C function levtree_levtree_init...